# Game Design Schools

Tags: game-design, education

Are there any  Colleges/Universities  (besides digipen i am aware of that one) that are centred around video game careers? Failing that any that have particularly good video game programs? preferably in Canada but not really necessary.

Comment: For the love of God do not go to Westwood College. Trust me.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search of "top game design schools" offered me a lot of top searches already.
This one seems to be from princetonreview is credible because it's known a lot for its rankings of top party schools and other quality-of-life ratings of college.

http://www.princetonreview.com/top-undergraduate-schools-for-video-game-design.aspx

I suggest checking the other links when doing a google search and you'd get more information out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Game Career Guide Digital Counselor](http://gamecareerguide.com/digital_counselor/). It gives you a bunch of filtering options when it comes to searching for a school related to what your main focus of study would be. From there you could probably narrow it down to a few schools and specifically research them instead of doing this extremely broad research.

Answer (score 0):

Reliable rule of thumb for most colleges: if it has a TV commercial somewhere, it's probably not worth your time. Local community colleges and trade schools that don't fulfill white collar jobs are the exceptions to this rule.

A college that would be worth looking into that's close to Digipen (and also in your country) is [Vancouver Film School](http://www.vfs.com). Needless to say, this one is also of a high pedigree and you'll probably need ridiculous amounts of talent to be admitted to and keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you don't need it to be in Canada,
There is a nice and very video game centric college here in melbourne (Australia) called QANTM. You can choose a bachelor degree in Games Animation, Games Design or Games Programming.

http://melbourne.qantm.com/en-gb/course/2488/

I have a couple of friends who are attending it and it is quite a full on course. I completed a double degree at Swinburne University which was computer sci/Multimedia(Games and Interactivity) but not enough of the subjects were focussed around video game creation for my liking.

Answer (score 0):

I went to [Champlain College](http://www.champlain.edu/undergraduate-studies/majors-and-programs/game-design-x14300.html) in Burlington, VT which is only about 2 hours south of the Canadian border. They have a program for Design, Art, and Programming. I studied design, but learned a fair bit of programming and am currently employed in the game industry so I can't really complain about the education I received.